# show leave record in each month

Tags: php, mysql

I have records coming from database like this for each row. what i want is to show each user record of leaves in each month like this.

**what i want to show**

```
Month      Annual Casual Medical Other
Jul 2014      4      2      -     -
Aug 2014      -      -      -     2
Sep 2014      1      3      1     -
```

**whats my result in php**

```
Month      Annual Casual Medical Other
Jul 2014      4      -      -     -
Aug 2014      -      -      -     2
Sep 2014      1      3      1     -
Jul 2014      -      2      -     -
```

I don't want that the month repeat like mentioned in what my result. if there is an annual, casual or any other type leave in Jul, the month should not repeat, and the record should show in a way like I mentioned above.

My SQL Query is:

```
SELECT `leaves`.id,
       `leaves`.emp_id,
       employee.employeeCode,
       employee.employeeName,
       employee.designation,
       department.`name` as department,
       employee.email, 
       employee.annualLeave,
       employee.casualLeave,
       employee.medicalLeave,
       employee.carryForward,
       YEAR(dateFrom) as YEAR,
       DATE_FORMAT(dateFrom, '%b') as MONTH,
       SUM(`leaves`.noOfDays) as totalNoLeaves ,
       `leaves`.type FROM 
       employee 
       INNER JOIN department ON (employee.deptt_id = department.id ) 
     LEFT JOIN `leaves` ON (employee.id = `leaves`.emp_id) 
 WHERE employee.id = '1' GROUP BY `leaves`.type, DATE_FORMAT(`leaves`.dateFrom, '%b') ORDER BY employee.id ASC
```

And my PHP code is:

```
$data= array();
while($result  = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$data[] = $result;
}

<table border="1" width="500" class="listing">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="record-view-label"><strong>Month</strong></th>
<td class="record-view-value"><strong><div align="center">Annual</div></strong></td>
<td class="record-view-value"><strong><div align="center">Casual</div></strong></td>
<td class="record-view-value"><strong><div align="center">Medical</div></strong></td>
<td class="record-view-value"><strong><div align="center">Other</div></strong></td>
</tr>
<?php 
foreach($data as $value){
if ($value['type'] == "Annual"){ $annual = $value['totalNoLeaves'];}else {$annual = "-";}
if ($value['type'] == "Casual"){ $casual = $value['totalNoLeaves'];}else {$casual = "-";}
if ($value['type'] == "Medical"){ $medical = $value['totalNoLeaves'];}else {$medical = "-";}
if ($value['type'] == "Other"){ $oth = $value['totalNoLeaves'];}else {$oth = "-";}
?>
<tr>
<th class="record-view-label"><?=$value['MONTH'].' - '.$value['YEAR'];?></th> 
<td class="record-view-value"><div align="center"><?=$annual;?></div> </td>
<td class="record-view-value"><div align="center"><?=$casual;?></div> </td>
<td class="record-view-value"><div align="center"><?=$medical;?></div> </td>
<td class="record-view-value"><div align="center"><?=$oth;?></div> </td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your current code.

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question.

Comment: Well then add up the numbers while GROUPing BY the month …

Comment: @JohnConde, please check,  I have added my code.

Comment: Looks better. Nominating for re-opening.

Comment: thanks @JohnConde, waiting for the help, still on hold :(

Comment: Anybody there to help me sort this out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use field value as a column name then you can easily solved this.
Use below query:

SELECT  `leaves`.id, SUM( CASE WHEN (`leaves`.type =  'Annual') THEN  `leaves`.noOfDays ELSE NULL END ) AS Annual, SUM( CASE WHEN (`leaves`.type =  'Casual') THEN  `leaves`.noOfDays ELSE NULL END ) AS Casual, SUM( CASE WHEN (`leaves`.type =  'Medical'
) THEN  `leaves`.noOfDays ELSE NULL END ) AS Medical, SUM( CASE WHEN (`leaves`.type =  'Other' ) THEN  `leaves`.noOfDays ELSE NULL END ) AS Other, 
`leaves`.emp_id, employee.employeeCode, employee.employeeName, employee.designation, department.`name` AS department, employee.email, employee.annualLeave, employee.casualLeave, employee.medicalLeave, employee.carryForward, YEAR( dateFrom ) AS YEAR, DATE_FORMAT( dateFrom,  '%b' ) AS 
MONTH , SUM(  `leaves`.noOfDays ) AS totalNoLeaves
FROM employee
INNER JOIN department ON ( employee.deptt_id = department.id ) 
LEFT JOIN  `leaves` ON ( employee.id =  `leaves`.emp_id ) 
WHERE employee.id =  '1'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`leaves`.dateFrom,  '%b') 
ORDER BY employee.id ASC